# Is there any established Fifa 11 Esports Leagues or Tournaments

Tags: fifa-11

Like there's tons of VODs you can watch for Starcraft 2, but is there any professional-level matchups to watch for Fifa 11? I am having a hard time finding any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question was asked a year ago, I'm going to assume you might be playing FIFA 12, which is the main tournament title right now. While there's not a lot of FIFA news in mainstream eSports, there are some tournaments that happen over the year like WCG, FIWC, and Insomnia that feature the title. Here are a few resources with match content you might find entertaining and useful:

World Cyber Game: http://www.wcg.com/renew/tv/tv_main.asp

Sweetpatch TV: http://www.youtube.com/user/Sweetpatch

FIFA Interactive World Cup: http://www.youtube.com/user/FIFATV/videos?query=FIFA+Interactive+2012

Koas TV: http://www.youtube.com/user/KaoSContingency/videos?query=fifa

European Gaming League: http://www.youtube.com/user/eglpro/videos?query=fifa

That's what I could find for now. All of these sources besides Sweetpatch, are recognizable eSports organizations and will most likely continue producing FIFA content. Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: It's no GSL or MLG, but I'll look into. Thanks.